# Singular Vector Decomposition and PCA interpretation

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization, svd, singular-values, principal-component-analysis

The covariance matrix of any data X -> N * D (N samples and D dimension ) would be Cov(X) = E[(X - E[X])(X - E[X])<sup>T</sup>]. Let's Assume (X - E[X])=Y. Thus Cov(X) = E[YY<sup>T</sup>]. Now from SVD we know that U and V are just eigenvectors of A<sup>T</sup>A and AA<sup>T</sup> respectively. Thus, we can just use Eigen decomposition of YY<sup>T</sup> as it is symmetric.

The confusion I face is how do you interpret this Cov(X) = Eigendecomposition(YY<sup>T</sup>) = PDP<sup>-1</sup>. From my point of view it is just a factorization of linear transformation.

How can we conclude that which dimension would have highest covariance from this factorization? I am having hard time interpreting it as anything but transformation, meaning if I multiply a vector with PDP<sup>-1</sup>, the vector will get transformed to a space where eigen vectors are basis. In this case they are orthonormal and hence its just rotation and then scaled and then put back to original space.

All I can view it as a factorization which tells us about the Cov(X) as a transformation rather than Cov(X) itself.

Comment: '@Peri Javia' was my answer helpful ? If so please mark it accordingly .

Answer (score 1):

According to Wikipedia [Principal Component Analyis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis) comes in two ways:

1. As a basis transformation (diagonalization) of the **covariance matrix**:
   $C=PDP^\top$
2. As a singular value decomposition of the (transposed) **data matrix**: $X^\top=U\Sigma W^\top$ (assuming we have already subtracted the mean from $X$)

Since $C=XX^\top=W\Sigma^2 W^\top$ and since $\Sigma$ is a diagonal $(d\times d)$-matrix it is clear that $\Sigma^2=D$ and $W=P\,.$ In other words, both approaches lead to the same diagonalization of the covariance matrix.

From basic linear algebra it is clear that the diagonal matrix $D$ contains the eigenvalues and the columns of $P$ are the eigenvectors. It is also clear that any permutation of those columns will just permute the diagonal elements of $D\,.$

We cannot conclude 'which dimension would have the highest covariance' **but** we know always which eigenvector corresponds to the highest, second highest, and so on, eigenvalue. That's all that counts.